g++ version flag not switching c++ version correctly
I have usually been using c++11 in the past, and using the "-std=c++11" flag with manual compilation and make files to do so. Now I want to use the filesystem library, which requires c++17 or beyond.
This should not be an issue by my understanding, as my g++ version is 11.4.0.
I tried changing the flag in my make file to "-std=c++17" but this didn't work, as I got a compilation error about "filesystem not naming a type" and some path references to c++11. Then I tried manually, and got the same thing.
Here's the (wsl) terminal command and the (start of the) result below:
g++ -std=c++17 fstesting.cc

fstesting.cc:3:17: error: ‘filesystem’ in namespace ‘std’ does not
name a type
3 | using fs = std::filesystem;
|                 ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/fs_fwd.h:37,
from /usr/include/c++/11/filesystem:44,
from fstesting.cc:1:

(this isn't formatted quite correctly, but you get the point)
What gives?

Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre] of your code, and also copy-paste the full and complete build-output (including the command) as text.

The compiler switches to the correct version just fine.
You are trying to use std::filesystem in a alias-declaration as if it's a type.

    alias-declaration:
        using identifier attribute-specifier-seqopt = defining-type-id ;

std::filesystem is not a type, it's a namespace. You might want a namespace-alias-definition instead.

    namespace-alias-definition:
        namespace identifier = qualified-namespace-specifier ;


You have 2 options as std::filesystem is a namespace.
a) "using" namespace - Then use the classes inside the filesystem namespace.
using namespace std::filesystem;  

path p1 = "/tmp/a.txt";

b) namespace alias
namespace fs = std::filessystem;

fs::path p1 = "/tmp/a.txt";

